# Reading / Writing to padding in c++

Tags: c++, padding

Is there a way to write to or at least read from padding added by the compiler to a struct in c++ , for example my compiler adds a padding of 3 bytes to the following struct

```
struct A {
      char a;
      int b;
};
```

Comment: Yes, because that's how it works. C++ says base classes are intialized first. If you are asking if the order is specified, it is. If this isn't what you are asking, consider being more specific about what exactly you would like to know.

Comment: The relationship between the base and derived constructors is up to you to decide. At least _one_ constructor in `base` will be called first, then at least _one_ in the derived class. You may have delegating on both too. Nothing says that if you use the default constructor in the derived class, the default `base` constructor will be used. That's up to you decide. The `base` class may not even have a default constructor.

Comment: @françois i want to know why these exist. Is there a reason or just because that's how c++ works

Comment: It is fundamental to C++ that base classes get constructed first, then the derived classes; and the destructors get called in reverse order. There are no exceptions to this rule; the only variation is which constructors of each class get invoked, which is established via other means.

Comment: @KenZa A derived class has all the members of the base class. If the base class needs to be initialized for these members to work correctly, the constructor needs to be called. If they don't, then the constructor doesn't do anything, in which case there is no harm in calling that constructor. So derived classes always start by initializing their base class components.

Comment: If you're interested in the why, you really should read The Design and Evolution of C++ by the man himself. My annoyance at some of the language features decreased markedly once I understood the design trade-offs behind them.

Comment: @françois but if the derived class has it's own constructors why would we still need to call the default constructor of the base class  , it doesnt seem like it serves any purpose , plus from what i understand default constructor of base class is always called first and then that of the derived class this means that the values of the last one are the ones to stick around and those created by the default constructor of base class are going to be overwritten right ? Wouldnt this be a performance issue ? Especially when having a lot of objects

Comment: It allows to base to prepare/teardown itself without the derived class caring about the specifics.

Comment: @pontus yes me too, i have come to understand that there must a good reason for every feature the author made in a specific way , probably based on experience or issues encountred when done in a different way , that's what i want to know

Comment: Because the derived class has no way to access the private members of the base. That's the one of the purposes I think.

Comment: @todd but if derived class has a default constructor itdoes get called after the default constructor of base is called , so based on what you said this means that a default constructor in a derived class serves no purpose ?

Comment: In order to construct an object of type `derived`, all components of `derived` must be constructed first.  This includes any base classes.

Comment: @KenZa The derived constructor's responsibility is to initialize the parts of itself that it adds. Those members that `Derive` have, but `Base` doesn't. It is not its responsibility to initialize the `Base` portion, there already exists a constructor for that. The derived class' implementer is not required to know about or even have access to the `Base`'s implementation details, the derived constructor may not even be capable of performing the initialization required by the `Base` class. By always calling a `Base` constructor first, you always get the most correct result.

Comment: Given the additional questions in the comments about "performance" and "serves no purpose", I am voting to close this question as needing details or clarity.  It seems that the question posted is based on incorrect assumptions that aren't detailed in the question.  It is still possible to [edit] this question describing why it is believed that _performance_ or _purpose_ is harmed by constructing a base class before constructing the derived class.

Comment: @ted do you mean that even if base has a default constructor i get to decide whether it gets called or not ?

Comment: @KenZa Yes. You can select any of the constructors in `base`. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/dPzbWdEz5)

Comment: @ted i see, thanks. But there must be at least one call to a constructur from base in this case correct ? We can't tell derived to call only its own constructurs and ignore all of the constructurs in base ?

Comment: @KenZa At least one of the constructors in base will be used, yes. What purpose would not calling any constructor have? Just make a default constructor (implicitly or explicitly) that does nothing and then you have that behavior. It will still be "called" (conceptually) but it'll do nothing (unless you have default values for member variables).

Comment: @ted sorry i have another question , what if we want derived to have its own default values which are going to be different from those of base, we cant create a default constructor in derived since it cannot access atributes insidz base , so we do this for example : `derived ( int x = 0 , ... ) : base ( x , ... )` ?

Comment: @KenZa As long as the base class has a constructor that takes the values you want, it's no problem: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/W5j1jnb7M)

Comment: @ted  what is that X(x) and X(1) , brace initilization ? But X was declared after you used it , why doesnt it give compiler error ? And you add semicolon before it too ? Thanks in advance ( a lot )

Comment: @KenZa `X(x)` initializes `X` with the argument `x`. `X(1)` is the initialization you get if you use the default constructor. So, the base class default and the derived default can initialize `X` with different values. All member variables are in scope when you define the class so it doesn't matter that they are declared after. In fact, it's pretty common to have the `private` members last in classes since they are not a part of the API that users of the class should think about too much.

Comment: @ted last question, in this case i can make the variables in base protected, this way i can give them different default values in derived classes than those in base right ? Or it is considered bad practice ?

Comment: @KenZa `protected` member variables are often frowned upon - and even if they are `protected`, you'll need a base class constructor to initialize them with the correct value. Otherwise you'll have to first default construct them, then change their value afterwards, which may be less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your first statement is not actually true.  It only applies if:

1. Your base class *has* a default constructor.
2. You don't specify which base class constructor to call in the definition of your derived class, which you might do, for example, like so:

```
Derived::Derived (int x) : Base (x) { }
```

As to why, well, it's a question of which class is responsible for what.  So:

- the base class is responsible for initialising itself and only itself
- likewise the derived class
- the derived class is responsible for calling any one of the base class constructors so that it is properly initialised, which the compiler will do by default, when it can

In short, it's all just common sense, really.  Certainly, nothing else would work as well.

Comment: every class has a constructor by default, and i didnt specify which constructor from base to call because that's what i want , i didnt not specify anything , this is the way c++ calls constructors if you do not specify anything so my question is perfectly fine

Comment: That's not true either.  If you define a user-defined constructor then the default constructor is implicitly deleted, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor.  You can override this behaviour (by declaring the default constructor with `= deleted`, for example), but that is opt-in.

Comment: i know that ... , in your answer you said it only applies if base class has a default constructor , so i said that every class has a constructur by default ( even if you do not define one ) and it will be the one to be called

Comment: Hmmm.  What made you ignore the information in my previous comment?

Comment: i dont understand. What did i ignore exactly ?

Comment: Pretty much all of it, seems.  Anyway, it's up to you, I won't post again.

Comment: sorry, i didnt mean it, but your answer is not what i'm looking for. Your answer is more about how this works in c++ , what i want is why they chose to do it this way and not another, for example why not give the constructor of derived access to variables of base to initialize them directly instead of having to call at least one constructor from base ( in addition to those in the derived if desired ) , it seemed like a possible performance issue to me. (I also had a misconception that the default constructor in derived has access to variables in base) . Thanks for your answer anyway.